# Eclipse JOptionPane graphical issue

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, joptionpane, java-6

When i run the line`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test");` in eclipse I get the message dialog but there seems to be a problem with the graphics. I have re-installed the latest JDK and have had no luck in solving the issue.

[image]

Comment: Are there any heavy threads running in the background?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't understand what you mean by heavy threads

Comment: Just to be sure: You are using the `JOptionPane` from the EDT, right?

Comment: @Ordous It has the same effect

Comment: This could be an issue with your video card/drivers; for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780564/java-swing-graphics-glitch

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you, the issue was a problem with my graphics card. I followed the link and it solved my issue.

Comment: I've had issues with Radeon cards as well, needing to disable DirectX and use OpenGL (or something like that)