# Java swing error (eclipse)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, window

Hello I'm a beginner in Java Swing Application Window 
  Here I face this problem in the graphics.

- Why this problem is appearing?
- How to solve it?

[Here's the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yvbN.png)

Here's the code

```
public class MainWindow {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JPasswordField passwordField;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MainWindow() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        private String txtUsername;
        private String txtPassword;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            txtPassword = passwordField.getText();
            txtUsername = textField.getText();
        }
    });
    btnLogin.setBounds(183, 181, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(183, 110, 150, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Username");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(106, 114, 94, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Password");
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(106, 153, 67, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);

    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField.setBounds(183, 147, 150, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(passwordField);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("Bus Station");
    lblNewLabel_2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(62, 11, 321, 51);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_2);
}
}
```

Comment: realy? without any code? how should we help you?

Comment: What is the problem? Can you be more precise? Paste stacktrace or screenshot if necessary, to help others.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780564/java-swing-graphics-glitch

Comment: Now that the OP has added the requested info, how about removing some downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly add your `Components` to the `JFrame`.
Make a nice `new JPanel()`, add the buttons and labels to it and then add ONLY this `JPanel` to the contentPane.

Edit:
Of course, you should use a proper `LayoutManager` to position your `Components`.